# get Variable in doInBackground Get out of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How to get Variable in doInBackground Get out of AsyncTask

Request Api url set new like and get new like and like mode

Now how to get new like and like mode out of AsyncTask for use setText

get like this from GetDataLike AsyncTask:

```
            new GetDataLike().execute(textViewQuoteId.getText().toString());
            String newLike = GetDataLike().newLike; // get like this from GetDataLike
            String modeLike = GetDataLike().modeLike; // get like this from GetDataLike
            textViewQuoteLike.setText("پسندیدم ("+newLike+")");
            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "لایک شما برای سخن "+textViewProfileName.getText().toString()+" ثبت شد.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Json result example:

```
{"Like":{"quote_like":"27","quote_like_mode":"1"}}
```

QuoteArrayAdapter.java

```
package com.example.adapter;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.R;
import com.example.model.QuoteDataModel;
import com.example.parser.JSONParser;
import com.example.utils.Keys;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;

import static android.content.Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE;

public class QuoteArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QuoteDataModel> {

    List<QuoteDataModel> modelList;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    // Constructors
    public QuoteArrayAdapter(Context context, List<QuoteDataModel> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        modelList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public QuoteDataModel getItem(int position) {
        return modelList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_row, parent, false);
            vh = ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
            view.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        QuoteDataModel item = getItem(position);

        vh.textViewQuoteContent.setText(item.getQuoteContent());
        vh.textViewProfileName.setText(item.getProfileName());
        vh.textViewQuoteLike.setText("پسندیدم ("+item.getQuoteLike()+")");
        vh.textViewQuoteCopy.setText("کپی");
        vh.textViewQuoteShare.setText("اشتراک");
        vh.textViewQuoteId.setText(item.getQuoteId());
        Picasso.with(context).load(item.getProfilePhoto()).placeholder(R.drawable.empty_profile_photo).error(R.drawable.empty_profile_photo).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(vh.imageViewProfilePhoto);

        return vh.rootView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final RelativeLayout rootView;
        public final ImageView imageViewProfilePhoto;
        public final TextView textViewQuoteContent;
        public final TextView textViewProfileName;
        public final TextView textViewQuoteLike;
        public final TextView textViewQuoteCopy;
        public final TextView textViewQuoteShare;
        public final TextView textViewQuoteId;
        public final TextView textViewQuoteLikeIcon;
        public final TextView textViewQuoteShareIcon;
        public final TextView textViewQuoteCopyIcon;

        private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageViewProfilePhoto, TextView textViewQuoteContent, TextView textViewProfileName, TextView textViewQuoteLike, TextView textViewQuoteCopy, TextView textViewQuoteShare, TextView textViewQuoteId, TextView textViewQuoteLikeIcon, TextView textViewQuoteShareIcon, TextView textViewQuoteCopyIcon) {
            this.rootView = rootView;
            this.imageViewProfilePhoto = imageViewProfilePhoto;
            this.textViewQuoteContent = textViewQuoteContent;
            this.textViewProfileName = textViewProfileName;
            this.textViewQuoteLike = textViewQuoteLike;
            this.textViewQuoteCopy = textViewQuoteCopy;
            this.textViewQuoteShare = textViewQuoteShare;
            this.textViewQuoteId = textViewQuoteId;
            this.textViewQuoteLikeIcon = textViewQuoteLikeIcon;
            this.textViewQuoteShareIcon = textViewQuoteShareIcon;
            this.textViewQuoteCopyIcon = textViewQuoteCopyIcon;
        }

        public static ViewHolder create(final RelativeLayout rootView) {
            ImageView imageViewProfilePhoto = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfilePhoto);
            final TextView textViewQuoteContent = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuoteContent);
            final TextView textViewProfileName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfileName);
            final TextView textViewQuoteLike = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuoteLike);
            TextView textViewQuoteCopy = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuoteCopy);
            TextView textViewQuoteShare = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuoteShare);
            final TextView textViewQuoteId = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuoteId);
            final TextView textViewQuoteLikeIcon = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuoteLikeIcon);
            final TextView textViewQuoteShareIcon = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuoteShareIcon);
            final TextView textViewQuoteCopyIcon = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuoteCopyIcon);

            textViewQuoteLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    new GetDataLike().execute(textViewQuoteId.getText().toString());
                    String currentLike = textViewQuoteLike.getText().toString();
                    currentLike = currentLike.replace("پسندیدم (","");
                    currentLike = currentLike.replace(")","");
                    int newLike = Integer.valueOf(currentLike.toString()) + 1;
                    textViewQuoteLike.setText("پسندیدم ("+newLike+")");
                    Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "لایک شما برای سخن "+textViewProfileName.getText().toString()+" ثبت شد.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            textViewQuoteLikeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    new GetDataLike().execute(textViewQuoteId.getText().toString());
                    String currentLike = textViewQuoteLike.getText().toString();
                    currentLike = currentLike.replace("پسندیدم (","");
                    currentLike = currentLike.replace(")","");
                    int newLike = Integer.valueOf(currentLike.toString()) + 1;
                    textViewQuoteLike.setText("پسندیدم ("+newLike+")");
                    Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "لایک شما برای سخن "+textViewProfileName.getText().toString()+" ثبت شد.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( rootView.getContext().getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
            textViewQuoteLikeIcon.setTypeface(font);
            textViewQuoteLikeIcon.setText(String.valueOf((char) 0xf164));

            return new ViewHolder(rootView, imageViewProfilePhoto, textViewQuoteContent, textViewProfileName, textViewQuoteLike, textViewQuoteCopy, textViewQuoteShare, textViewQuoteId, textViewQuoteLikeIcon, textViewQuoteShareIcon, textViewQuoteCopyIcon);
        }
    }


    static class GetDataLike extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String quoteId = params[0];

            JSONObject jsonObject = JSONParser.getDataFromWeb("http://example.com/api-service/v1/platform_quote_like/?id="+quoteId);
            try {
                if (jsonObject != null) {
                    if(jsonObject.length() > 0) {
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Keys.KEY_LIKE);
                        int lenArray = array.length();
                        if(lenArray > 0) {
                            for(int jIndex = 0; jIndex < lenArray; jIndex++) {
                                JSONObject innerObject = array.getJSONObject(jIndex);
                                String quote_like = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_QUOTE_LIKE);
                String quote_like_mode = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_QUOTE_LIKE_Mode);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                Log.i(JSONParser.TAG, "" + je.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

    public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

            int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
            int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

            Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
            if (squaredBitmap != source) {
                source.recycle();
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                    BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

            float r = size / 2f;
            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

            squaredBitmap.recycle();
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return "circle";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at how async tasks work, you want to do this in your onPostExcecute of your asynctask and not in a synchronous way as you suggested

Comment: How to do without doing AsyncTask, please example request api and get new like number and mode like without AsyncTask if AsynsTask is Problem

Comment: AsyncTask is the best thing to use, you are just using it wrong. As I said, it would help if you'd read some docs and examples about asynctasks. In this case you should use the `onPostExecute` of the asynctask

Answer (score 2):

you just have to return string from doInBackground method and in onPostExecute method you can setText.for more than one values which is in your case you should do like this

```
   public class CollectValues{ 
public String quote_like;
public String quote_like_mode;}
```

and now in doInBackground method you should do like this

```
CollectValue cv = new CollectValue();
    cv.quote_like=//your response;
    cv.quote_like=//your response;
            return cv;
```

and finally in onPostExecute method you should do like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CollectValues cv) {
        //your textview here
        textview1.setText(cv.quote_like);
        textview2.setText(cv.quote_like_mode);
    }
```

this will solve your problem..

Comment: Thanks, I want out of AsyncTask

Comment: basically your onPostExecute method will run on UI thread so..i cant understand what you exactly want?

Comment: Save value you need in `onPostExecute()` to `SharedPreferences` and retreive it where you need it.